# Is cognito required to use AWS Amplify Package for s3 storage on iOS?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-ios

From what I can tell, cognito is required for me to impliment the amplify storage package into my iOS project, can someone please confirm this incase I am missing something?

Additionally, I understand the AWS prefers SDK users to impliment amplify rather than their old SDK's, however why would they force you to use cognito? Is there anyway to use access keys to authentication with the amplify storage package vs cognito? Really not looking to pay just for uploading images with each user, seems like an unecessary cost vs Firebase...